# Python ElementTree Namespaces

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Env:
Python 2.7
Windows 8.1

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="DataModel">
            <EntityContainer Name="EC1" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Attributes" EntityType="Model.Attribute"/>
                <EntitySet Name="AttributeControlTypes" EntityType="Model.AttributeControlType"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

test code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from cStringIO import StringIO

def parse(self):
    events = ("end", "start-ns", "end-ns", "start")
    namespaces = []
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(StringIO(self.document), events=events):
        if event == "start-ns":
            print "startns: {}".format(elem)
            namespaces.append(elem)
        elif event == "end-ns":
            removed = namespaces.pop()
            print "removedns: {}".format(removed)
        elif event == "start":
            print elem.tag
```

My understanding is if a tag has a namespace attached to it then all the child elements should also be in the same namespace.  When I try to parse the above XML I would have expected the "entitySet" elements to be in the namespace defined in "EntityContainer":

output:

```
startns: (u'edmx', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx')
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx}Edmx
startns: (u'm', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata')
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx}DataServices
startns: ('', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm')
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm}Schema
startns: (u'p6', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation')
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm}EntityContainer
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm}EntitySet
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm}EntitySet
removedns: (u'p6', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation')
removedns: ('', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm')
removedns: (u'm', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata')
removedns: (u'edmx', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx')
```

ElementTree sees the start of the namespace(p6) but seems to add the "EntityContainer" child elements into the namespace of the "Schema" element.  Is this working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is working as expected.

> > My understanding is if a tag has a namespace attached to it then all the child elements should also be in the same namespace.

Actually, if a tag declares a *default namespace* then all of the child elements will also be in the same namespace.

Your EntityContainer element is like this:

```xml
        <EntityContainer xmlns:p6="FOO" ...>
```

This creates a new namespace, but does not place EntityContainer nor its children in it.

To satisfy your expectation, you would have to declare a default namespace, like so:

```
        <EntityContainer xmlns="FOO" ...>
```

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration
- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp